# Does this site support questions asking to evaluate alternative solutions to a problem and if yes, how can I ask them?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, on-topic-definition, subjective

This is how I tend to use this site (and other SE sites):

1. I work.
2. I run into a problem I cannot solve myself (at least not easily, without devoting very substantial time or effort I cannot now devote). For example:

   1. I don't know how to progress in my task.
   2. **I can see more than one way to progress, but cannot evaluate which way to choose. <sub>(flip a coin?)</sub>**
   3. I cannot explain to myself why something that seems true is indeed true.
   4. Etc.
3. I need help of someone more knowledgeable/experienced than me to progres!
4. Type the question into an appropriate SE site
5. Does the *Similar questions* box show this question? If yes, read. If not, ask.

From then... this is a coin flip for me. I'm notoriously incapable of grasping the fine lines between an on-topic question and off-topic question. Very often there are two very similar questions, one of which is highly upvoted, while the other one is severly downvoted and/or closed - and I cannot spot the difference!

Thus, unfortunately, I cannot craft my question so that it would be well-received, nor can I predict whether my question will be well-received or not.

Same thing happened with this question: [How important is it to have a consistent technological stack?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/400517/how-important-is-it-to-have-a-consistent-technological-stack)

According to early feedback, my question is off-topic because it is an opinion-based question.

But I bring up *many* examples of questions that seem to me to be similar in nature (go for solution X or Y, and why?) that were well-received on this site. Two examples of my own questions: [If-else ladder that is supposed to catch all conditions - should a redundant final clause be added?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/398721/if-else-ladder-that-is-supposed-to-catch-all-conditions-should-a-redundant-fin) and [Pointers vs keeping indices of objects stored in a central (associative) array?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/397166/pointers-vs-keeping-indices-of-objects-stored-in-a-central-associative-array)

Granted - the question I'm talking about now is a little bit... peculiar. In short: I am facing two possible solutions, X and Y, out of which X takes magnitudes of time more than Y (rewrite half of existing code to a different programming language vs dont rewrite). I have a problem because I find myself having a gag reflex towards the easier solution of these two... I ask myself: *Why do I hate Y so much?* - the answer is: Because I want consistency. If I use technology stack `${Stack}` in my project, I should be using it for all problems solvable by this stack. Ugh... Does my reasoning make sense? I start suspecting I may have fallen to the trap of [all-or-nothing thinking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_(psychology)): Either everything must be written in JS, or everything must be written in .Net, I must not write half of my project in JS and the other half in .Net.

Did I? Is here a real problem or am I making up a problem where there, in fact, there is none?

The problem seems to reduce to the question: **Am I correct in wanting maximum consistency in the technological stack I use?** - I cannot answer this myself, I need help of someone more knowledgeable and experienced! => Ask. <sub>Be told this question is a bad fit because it is subjective.</sub>

I read this: [The real borderline for "Opinion based" in Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6473/the-real-borderline-for-opinion-based-in-software-engineering) And also the *opinion-based* part of this: [Why was my question closed or down voted?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6491#6491)

I now have a hypothesis: **My question is opinion-based and off-topic precisely because I cannot describe an actual problem, rather, I need to ask if X is indeed a problem.** Is this correct? If I have a question when I'm unsure if the problem actually exists of if I'm making up a problem where there is in fact none, is such a Q automatically off-topic?

Comment: [If there are two ways of approaching a task, how should one choose between them?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/351356)

Comment: After rereading the [meta question](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6473/the-real-borderline-for-opinion-based-in-software-engineering) you linked to, I am not sure what you want to know what is not already answered there. And your tech stack question is very similar to a religious-war question like "should I use programming language X or Y" (ok, it is more "should I combine X with Y and Z, or better X with X'?", but the difference is IMHO not that huge).

Comment: There's a difference between asking if ice cream is a health snack and asking if chocolate or vanilla is better.

Answer (score 3):

With regards to the question [How important is it to have a consistent technological stack?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/400517/how-important-is-it-to-have-a-consistent-technological-stack), that question can be paraphrased as

> I currently have a technology stack with technology A for the front-end and technology B for the backend. Recent developments in the technologies have made it possible to use either for both the front-end and the backend.
>
> Should I rewrite my entire application in technology A or technology B.

This looks very much like you have fallen into the trap of all-or-nothing thinking and you are asking us to make a choice that we can't make for you.

Suppose user X would have answered that you must use technology A because it is best and user Y answered the same for technology B, how much would that have helped you in making your choice? That is what the close reason "primarily opinion based" means.