# The system supports questions with multiple answers poorly (and is becoming worse at it)

Tags: discussion, answer-quality, quality

**TL;DR** Can the system do something to help us more efficiently handle quality of the content in questions with multiple answers?

---

Recently I've seen notes from Stack Exchange staff about how it would be nice if site would allow for broader, softer kind questions. This was [said by Robert Cartaino here](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7650/31260):

> The idea that there are hordes of people just waiting flood the site for want of a single precedent was one of those things we worried about before we had anything to back it up. But if you haven't noticed, Stack Exchange has moved on from a lot of those old adages foretelling of widespread doom in ways that simply never materialized in actual use... *every* question must have exactly one absolutely factual answer. ...

...and [by Jon Ericson here](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7761/31260):

> Given quality of users on this site, there's no reason opinions (backed by research and experience) shouldn't be useful to other programmers...

Thing is though, the system makes it difficult (I would say, unnecessarily difficult) to produce and maintain quality content in questions with many answers. It doesn't provide any means to make it easier and some features even tend to incentivize low quality content in questions of this kind.

Current UI doesn't offer any means to help answerers and readers find / avoid repeating what was stated before. Combined with being very easy to post an answer, this leads to useless answers that don't add anything over what was posted before. This is noticeable even in questions with brief answers which are easy to check ([example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271158/839601)) and when answers are lengthy, things become even worse.

This penalizes web search visitors, forcing them to read same points over and over and over again. Letting repetitive answers proliferate is a step toward old-fashioned "forums", and quite a substantial one I think.

Particular feature that essentially encourages low quality content is Hot Network Questions.

To set the record straight for readers not familiar with its purpose - it is established pretty firmly and it has nothing to do with content quality. The feature is there only to show network wide audience entertaining / interesting questions. If you're interested, refer MSE for more details on that: [What is the Goal of “Hot Network Questions”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/219922/165773)

Per se, entertainment aspect of HNQ looks pretty acceptable and I don't think it should necessarily be that it makes a critical obstacle in maintaining quality content. Thing is though, as implemented currently... it really does.

HNQ, the way it is now, make maintaining quality content cumbersome and painful. Problems with content quality in hot questions are well known for a long time ([1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164078/165773), [2](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5413/31260)), and it keeps happening here and now, see for example [Recent Trouble With Popularity](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7525/recent-trouble-with-popularity)

---

Over years, Stack Exchange tried various ways to handle questions with multiple answers but none of these seemed to work.

- [Jeff Atwood's warning](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86895/165773) was probably the first one,

  > Did you read through all the existing answers first to make sure your answer will be contributing something new?

All I can say about it is that it doesn't work, has never worked and is unlikely to ever work.

- Another thing they tried was automatic conversion to community wiki when there are many answers.

This worked... sorta, in the sense that it made it easier to downvote low quality answers (without incurring rep penalty) and removed incentive to flood popular questions with answers in a (frankly, quite realistic) hope to gain a bit of rep with a random upvote.

The problem with this trick is, it had some *very* ugly side effects due to involved rep denial from users providing quality content and in the end it was [deservedly discarded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228940/165773). Thing is though, nothing was done to compensate loss of features used to counter issues in questions with many answers.

Sure, there's standard rhetoric about voting down low quality answers but tell me, how many users can afford rep loss of voting this way, say, 5-10 of total 20 non-CW answers in a question? how many of them can afford doing this every month? every week? And if you additionally consider ["sympathy upvotes"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311408/839601) frequently happening to such answers in popular questions (each worth more than 4 votes down rep wise), this starts looking like a wishful thinking.

- Another approach that was tried about two years ago is randomizing hot questions.

This seemed to work at first but as time passed by it revealed signs of inability to scale. Shuffling 100 hot questions to 100K site visitors works, shuffling same amount to 1 million will break and essentially return us back to old known issues with "snowball effect" when questions stick in the list solely because they were advertised there.

- Somewhere along the way they implemented special adjustment for Stack Overflow questions, which strongly pushes these from hot list after 7 hours.

This seems to work, in the sense that there aren't very loud complaints about hot questions at MSO anymore (like it was in the past with ["croissants"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190106/165773)). Still, this doesn't resolve problems at other sites. And still, even SO is having garbage answers problem in questions that acquire popularity and high views organically, not via hot questions.

- Yet another feature intended to help control answers quality is question protection, which makes it impossible to answer for users having less than 10 on-site reputation.

By design, protection is intended to handle only cases of extreme abuse. It doesn't provide any means against low quality answers posted by users with over 10 rep. Also, due to some implementation specifics, even very limited functionality it offers frequently turns out useless in hot questions.

---

**Can the system do something to help us more efficiently handle quality of the content in questions with multiple answers?**

Comment: @tchrist "system" is Stack Exchange software, see eg section of the question "tried various ways..." and [this answer](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/7771/31260)

Comment: @tchrist http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/posts/7770/revisions (I forgot about this funny limitation on suggested edits, sorry)

Comment: As someone who values reading multiple answers to a question, I think the voting mechanism is enough for me. Answers worth my time reading are at the top, and if I am seeking caveats or alternatives there are other posts to go through. Also personally, seeing a single upvoted answer is often not enough for me. I like to see alternatives that answer is compared against, and don't even mind seeing similar answers that reaffirm the top-voted one. The key that makes SE so useful to me is all of them are Answers to the Question, and they don't stray off-target.

Comment: @Rachel your perspective seems to be much different from mine because I use different sort order (active). Would be really helpful to know stats for what kind order is most preferred but unfortunately my request for that hangs ignored: [How many votes and flags are cast by users preferring particular answer order (active / oldest / votes)?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250527/165773)

Comment: Do you have any examples of recent (~post NPR) questions that were overwhelmed by multiple poor answers?

Comment: @Yannis with _current_ site norms, answer quality issues look pretty manageable to me (multiple answers still are troublesome in off-topic questions though). Post is intended to address recent ideas about relaxing these norms: "notes from Stack Exchange staff about how it would be nice if site would allow for broader, softer kind questions"

Comment: ...guess at the end of this lengthy post one can simply forget what was written in the beginning :)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what problem you are trying to solve here. You talk about repetitive answers, yet I don't even remember the last time I've seen a question on Programmers being overwhelmed by repetitive or otherwise poor answers. Sure, there's the occasional noob answer that doesn't add anything new, but is that a problem worthy of this long diatribe? Why does the system needs to be adjusted in any way? Where exactly is it failing?

Comment: To be more specific: How do you think the system should have handled [these popular questions with multiple answers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/search?q=views%3A5000+answers%3A5+created%3A2015)?

Comment: @Yannis I am not sure I understand what you don't understand. With current norms (settled more or less firmly 2-3 years ago), everything looks under control, just like you say. Post is not about what we have now, but about suggestions to change it

Comment: I don't see any suggestion to change our scope or norms in your quotes. Programmers was never a "one answer to rule them all" site, and opinions (backed by research and experience) have always been acceptable answers here. The quotes may just be a subtle reminder that we [have taken a good idea to a ridiculous extreme](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/7723/the-number-of-votes-required-to-close-and-reopen-questions-is-temporarily-reduce/7761#comment23396_7734)....

Comment: ridiculous or not, this way we have answer quality issues under control, as your own observations suggest. I can understand those willing to try softer approach but want us to realise that the system is designed sub-optimally (softly speaking) to handle this

Comment: I have no idea what this is asking. You just sort of launch into trying to back up your proposal without actually clearly stating what it is. What does "handle quality of the content" mean? And what's not "efficient" about how it's currently performed? And what in heck does "question has multiple answers" have to do with anything?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit it took you how long, [5 minutes](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/26104794#26104794) to read whole post and check the referred links with examples and related discussions? no wonder then

Comment: **["...becoming worse at it"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/276197/165773 "additional barrier on protecting questions")**

Comment: gnat, what you want to have is a Wiki. Just transform SO into a Wiki and the problem with multiple answers goes away.

Comment: @Trilarion no. The simple fact that SE successfully coexists with Wikipedia proves that its Q&A format has value, that it fills important niche and serves strong demand. Transform SO to Wiki and... yet another Q&A site will arise to cover the gap. I just want this format to scale smoother. It works great up to 3-5 answers in question and it manages to do more or less well up to 7-10 answers and I believe that with appropriate tuning it would be able to smoothly handle as many answers as needed

Comment: "I believe that with appropriate tuning it would be able to smoothly handle as many answers as needed ..." - Okay, it's worth a try. I am less optimistic there. I think for more than say 10 answers a Wiki like effort (all write into a single answer) is better suited.

Comment: well this approach seems to be prone to abuse @Trilarion - to the worst kind of it - to a _systemic_ abuse. Imagine 2-3 idiots jumping from sidebar into hot question with their oh-so-important "answers", why would we let them that easily mess into a work of prior answerers. Automatic wiki triggering by formal criteria was tried in the past, and ended in tears and SE mgmt now even seems to instruct moderators: ["If anyone requests removal of a forced Community Wiki setting, it should be removed without hesitation"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279368/165773), go figure

Answer (score 1):

As an example, here are some ideas of what can be considered:

- When there are many answers already, [let users compare draft of their post against prior answers](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2562/168). This would make it naturally harder to add yet another answer as their amount increases (note how this isn't limited to low rep users, as opposed to protection). This would also help responsible users ensure that their answer doesn't repeat what was stated already.
- [Get rid of first day voting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/237661/165773). This would help taming careless upvotes from passers by armed with association bonus. "Wanna vote? stick with us! (for at least a day or two)".
- [Introduce more scalable randomisation of hot questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/247195/165773) by picking more than 100 "candidate" questions for hot list. This would ensure that audience attention is spread more evenly and help tame "snowball effect".
- [Give elevated protection privileges to 30K users in questions with 3 or more answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268729/165773) and [don't count reputation gained within checked question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242942/165773) to trigger automatic protection. This would make protection of hot and organically popular questions more usable.

Comment: "...it is quite likely for suggested proposal to stay ignored. It has to be difficult to justify studying and tuning a feature that is designed in a way guaranteeing a negligible impact on a main site in SE network." ([Make hot questions with multiple answers age away faster on smaller / subjective-ish sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250154/165773))